# Finding unique hostnames in Python 2.x

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, python-2.7, aggregation-framework

I am collecting data from different datasources which all push to different collections in a MongoDB. All datasources have a field which stores the hostname of a particular system. However, some have the hostname alone (i.e HOSTNAME1) while others have the hostname along with the domain name (i.e HOSTNAME1.XXX.XXX.COM). My task is to get a count of unique hostnames across all datasources. It is quite possible that one datasource may give me HOSTNAME1 while another may give me HOSTNAME1.XXX.XXX.COM. I am currently using the aggregation method "addtoSet" to filter out any duplicate hostnames that share the same format. Any suggestions on how to account for hostnames that do not share the same format and are not unique? Solutions using Python 2.x are preferred but not required.

```
    def uniqueCount (collName, uploadDate):

        sysList = list(cursor.aggregate([ { '$match':{'UPLOAD_DATE':uploadDate} }, { '$group': {
                        '_id': collName,
                        'uniqueHosts': {'$addToSet': {'$toUpper':'$HOSTNAME'}}
                    }}]))

        return len(sysList[0]['uniqueHosts'])
```

Comment: Where is your current effort?

Comment: @user3483203 I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by current effort. Would you mind rephrasing?

Comment: Where is your current attempt at solving your own problem.

Comment: What have you done so far, code-wise? Please include this in your original post.

Comment: This seems an awful lot like homework, and while we'd be happy to help you we are not a free code-writing service. You won't get any meaningful help without first giving an example of what you've done so far that we can work from.

Comment: I have added what I have so far

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close - just transform the `HOSTNAME` field. It can be done fully on the DB side, using [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt) and [`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/#exp._S_split):

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: ...,
        // Set of HOSTNAME.split('.')[0]
        uniqueHosts: {$addToSet: {$arrayElemAt: [{$split: ['$HOSTNAME', '.']}, 0]}}
    }}
])
```